# Angular2 “expression has changed after it was checked” exception

Tags: angular

I have the following button in my template:

```
<button type="button" class="mgmButton" (click)="onSave()" [disabled]="saveDisabled()">Save</button>
```

The button is disabled based on the result of the saveDisabled function.

```
saveDisabled(): boolean {
    this.validationMessage = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tableData.length; i++) {
        let row = this.tableData[i];
        if (row.edit) {
            if (row.data.roleCode == null || row.data.roleCode == '' ||
                row.data.grantProgramCode == null || row.data.grantProgramCode == '') {
                this.validationMessage = 'Row ' + (i + 1) + ' has not filled in all required fields. ';
            }
        }
    }

    if(this.validationMessage == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

An earlier version of the function didn't build the validationMessage, it just returned true or false.  That worked w/o any errors.  But when I added the validationMessage property to the method/component/template, I started getting the “expression has changed after it was checked” exception.

Based on other posts it looks like this occurs because I'm changing the validationMessage variable while change detection is still happening.  I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on or the best way to get rid of the error.

Update:

I created a custom validator and it almost works perfectly.

My component has an array of data called tableData.  Each row in tableData is an object that gets displayed as a row in an html table in the template.  Sometimes a row is in a read-only mode, other times the data is in edit mode and so certain columns in the row are input fields, select drop-downs, etc.

The custom validator is applied to the form tag.  It takes tableData as the input.  All my validation logic works, and if the validator returns an error I display it in the template. (I did have to turn the tableData into a json string and then parse it to get the hand-off between component and validator to work correctly.)

But there seems to be an issue with the timing.  Let's say that a given row is in edit mode and the user changes the value of a select menu.  This select is bound to a property in one of the rows of tableData.  The validation in the form is triggered, but the data passed in has the old value of the select, not the new one.  In essence, the validation of the form happens before the data binding on a table row updates the backing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vilmantas correctly described what is happening. What he didn't say though is that this approach is incorrect in general. It should be the other way around - disabled flag should be calculated based on validity flag that is already calculated before change detection even starts, not at the same time.

Angular 2 provides special validation mechanics exactly for this task: interface Validator which you can implement in your custom directive, and this same directive can provide itself as a multi-provider of NG_VALIDATORS token. Below is the example from one of my projects.

Also, validators can be asynchronous (provider for NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS token), this is built-in option too. In this case you can consider "pending" flag to paint some indicator of pending validation, like checking user name availability by calling some web service.

After you provide this validator to ngModel you can just use standard ngModel.errors map with values, or ngModel.valid flag (and other flags too - there are bunch of them) to figure out if there were any errors and enable/disable controls based on it. Using this approach you don't need to even consider when it gets executed - angular will take care of everything for you.

Of course, you have to organize this thing so that it would be available in the template context, I mean correct imports/exports in some module(s)/component(s) and such stuff.

```
import {Directive, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS} from '@angular/forms';
import {IDateValidationResult} from './date-validator.interfaces';
import {moment} from '../../../shared/moment';

const DATE_VALIDATOR = {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValidatorDirective),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector:
        '[whatever-selector-you-want]',
    providers: [DATE_VALIDATOR]
})
export class DateValidatorDirective implements Validator {

    validate = (control: AbstractControl): IDateValidationResult => {
        if (!control) {
            return {required: true};
        }
        if (control.value === undefined) {
            return {required: true};
        }
        if (control.value === null) {
            return {invalidFormat: true};
        }
        let m = moment(control.value);
        if (!m.isValid()) {
            return {invalidFormat: true};
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="myModel" whatever-selector-you-want #myDateCtrl="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="myDateCtrl.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="myDateCtrl.errors.required">The date is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="myDateCtrl.errors.invalidFormat">Date format is invalid</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've created a few custom validators for basic forms.  I didn't use it in this situation because the validation logic will ultimately span multiple input fields and will also have to look at other rows in the table.  Column 1, 2, 3 must be a unique combo in all rows in the table.  Stuff like that.

Comment: @josh_in_dc, I see no difference. You can implement this complex validator for the whole form exactly the same way and check all the data in the form - tables with columns/rows, with values somehow related to each other, with whatever your form holds - any way you prefer. The point is that validation should not be driven by change detection in any way. It should be driven by whatever angular provides us specifically for this purpose. With that approach I don't care when and how it gets triggered and when change detection is happening there. It just works.

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm a little unsure how to implement it.  Every example of validation I've seen is at the input level and not the form.  The validator interface looks like it's only for AbstractControls, and when I look at the API doc for ngForm, it doesn't look like it extends AbstractControl.  So if I write a method that handles all the form level validation, how do I tie that into Angular's validation process?

Comment: So I created a custom validator that just logs some information to the console and applied it to my form and it works. So I definitely missed something in the API docs about ngForm.  I can improve the validator to take the component's business data object as an input field. Not everything in the table will be in form controls, so the abstract control that's passed to the validate method doesn't have all the data needed to perform the validation.  So I can get all the information I need into the validator to do the validation.  So I think I can get this done the angular2 way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I solved by adding ChangeDetectionStrategy from angular core.

```
import {  Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Vilmantas explained it pretty well. You're changing a binding (`validationMessage`) without triggering a new round of change detection, hence the error. It serves as a warning that the current value of `validationMessage` might not be reflected in the UI until something comes along in the future that *does* trigger change detection.

To fix, just trigger change detection manually after updating the validation message:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class Whatever {
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    myMethod() {
        // do stuff here
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); // detect changes
    }
}
```

Angular does have great built in support for forms, though, I do agree that would be preferable. This code you have now appears to iterate over the entire tableData array for every table row, and it will run many times during change detection. At the very least, you might want to pass `i` to it as a parameter (it's available in the `ngFor` loop) and save yourself the `for` loop.

Comment: I'll try triggering the change detection again.  I did once and it resulted in a max size of call stack exceeded error, but I think I had an error in the logic of my method.  

The function does have to look at all the data to determine if the save button is disabled or not.  I have other buttons and methods that apply to single rows, and in that instance I do pass the index from ngFor to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the angular2 internals, however I imagine it is something like this:

- `validationMessage` appears before the `Save` button on the template.
- When template is rendered for the first time, `validationMessage` has no value.
- Algorithm proceeds and now `saveDisabled()` is called which in turn changes `validatonMessage` value.
- => now angular complains that the value of already-rendered/checked `validationMessage` has changed within one rendering/check cycle.

To solve the problem, it would be best to move the validation code out of `saveDisabled()` method and store the boolean result into a field or you could even use the same `validationMessage` to disable the button:

```
<button type="button" ... [disabled]="validationMessage">Save</button>
```

(empty or null string will evaluate to false, non-empty message - to true)

Try to put the code where `tableData` is modified.

However, if your `tableData` is some kind of a form, the standard angular2 form with validators (standard or custom) would most likely be even better.

Comment: It is a form, but without a form tag in the template.  It's just input fields in a table with a variable number of rows that the user can edit at any given time.  All actions are triggered by (change) or (click) events.  So I could call the saveDisabled function from all the locations that change the contents of tableData.  And then change the disabled input on the button like you showed.